# Finding previous records after specified one and joining them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have this table, where players actions are being recorded. I would like to find out where people buy their equipment (`Item` Bow or Sword). The equipment can be bought in Shop or in Auction (the place can be found in `Action` column). So when the player buys an item, we need to find `Action`  Shop or Auction (depends on which one of them occured last before an item was bought)

```
**User       Time        Action         Item** 
  1          12:00       Auction
  2          12:01       Shop
  3          12:04       Shop
  4          12:09       Shop        
  4          12:15       Buy             Bow
  2          12:15       Auction
  2          12:19       Auction
  1          12:25       Chat    
  4          12:33       Auction         
  3          12:47       Chat
  1          12:47       Buy             Sword
  2          12:47       Buy             Bow
  3          12:50       Buy             Sword
  4          12:52       Buy             Bow
  3          12:56       Buy             Bow
```

The resulut should be

```
**Time        Item         Place**
 12:15        Bow          Shop
 12:47        Sword        Auction
 12:47        Bow          Auction
 12:50        Sword        Shop
 12:52        Bow          Auction
 12:56        Bow          Shop
```

I think I migh have a clue how to solve it with cross apply in mssql, but is it possible to solve it without it? I might have to use the query in hive as well. I would be grateful for any answer. Thank you!

Comment: What flavour of SQL Server are you using? If you are using 2008, you could use a `Common Table Expression` and, if you include the `ROW_NUMBER()` in it, you could join the CTE to itself on `b.row_num_alias = a.row_num_alias-1`

Comment: @DuncanHowe that would work all the way back to 2005 too.

Comment: @Aaron - Indeed - but I have seen performance issues using CTE's in 2005, that didn't manifest in 2008. For 2005 I prefer to use temporary tables.

Comment: Sorry, but why dont you wanna use OUTER APPLY?
It will be straight and faster

Comment: @DuncanHowe do you have any specific references? I have never seen any performance deltas between those versions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I don't. It was probably more to do with poorly designed (for designed read evolved) database and badly written CTE's, because not all CTE's suffered. However, exactly the same query ran quicker under 2008 than 2005, and replacing the CTE's with temporary tables in 2005 gave us better performance. Could it be something to do with the optimizer being more forgiving and intelligent in how it plans the query?

Comment: @DuncanHowe Sure, could be a lot of things. I don't think it's fair to say that CTEs in 2005 are worse than 2008 because of one experience you had that may very well have been explained by something else entirely.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'm not saying they are worse in 2005 - I am just saying that it happened and it is something to watch out for. In our case the problem didn't show itself until we went into production, at which point there is a whole raft of other factors to consider (load, configuration differences, physical architecture of the servers, et.c and so forth)

Comment: @DuncanHowe right, I'm just saying the general suggestion in your first comment that CTEs are only valid in 2008+ seems misleading, and now I'm even more opposed to it because it is biased.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - All I can say is that I personally will use temporary tables in 2005 and maybe CTE's in 2008+, but that is my preference based upon my experience. I am sure you also make decisions that are biased by experience.

Comment: @DuncanHowe sure, I won't use MERGE in any version because there are many *documented* bugs. I will not swear off of CTEs on an entire version because of some obscure scenario that I'm not even sure were CTEs' fault.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I am not saying to not use CTE's in 2005. I love them, especially recursive ones. All I am saying is that in my development experience I have encountered a situation where a CTE ran poorly in a 2005 environment, but like lightning in a 2008 environment. I forgot to mention that the DB was in 2005 compatibility mode as well which would suggest that version 10 brought some forgiveness/intelligence to our query. I will see if I can find the query in our TFS history.

Comment: @DuncanHowe I think you're missing my point. You don't need to prove to me that you had one bad experience with a CTE on SQL Server 2005 that might have had nothing at all to do with the fact that you were using a CTE (unless it was recursive, I bet a derived table would have yielded the same problem, or it would have been resolved by recompiling the query, updating stats, etc). My point is that it is misleading to say that someone can only use a CTE if they are running 2008+, which is what your original comment sounded like.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - and your first comment points this out, and I then agreed with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this (and I'm guessing you might like user in there as well, eh?)

**UPDATED ANSWER** thanks to Tim's suggestion

```
with p as    -- pick purchases
(SELECT [user], [time] purchased, [item]
   FROM actions 
   WHERE [action] = 'Buy'
), e as      -- pick entrances where something can be bought
(SELECT [user], [time] entered, [action] place
   FROM actions
   WHERE [action] IN ('Auction', 'Shop')
), j as      -- join purchases with all prior entrances
(SELECT p.[user], p.[purchased], p.[item],
        e.[entered], e.[place]
   FROM p
   JOIN e   on p.[user]=e.[user]
           and p.[purchased]>=e.[entered]
), r as      -- rank entrance closeness to purchase
(SELECT *, row_number() over( partition by [user],[purchased],[item] 
                              order by [entered] desc ) as rnk
   FROM j
)            -- select only where entrance is the closest
SELECT [user],[purchased],[item],[place]
  FROM r
  WHERE rnk = 1
  order by [user],[purchased],[item]
```

*Caveat:* TSQL is not my native dialect ;-)

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thank you and Tim as well :)

Comment: I assume your time column includes date too, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select time, item, (
  select top 1 Actions.action
  from   Actions
  where  Actions.[User] = buy.[user] and
         Actions.action in ('shop', 'auction') and
         Actions.time < buy.time
  order by Actions.time desc
                   )
from Actions as buy
where action = 'buy'
```

tested thanks to sqlfiddle provided by Tim Schmelter (great tool, I did not know about!!)